# The relationship between random variables, distribution functions and probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, and a random variable $X\colon\Omega\to\Bbb{R}$, we can associate with it its distribution function $F\colon \Bbb{R}\to[0,1]$ defined as
\begin{align*}
F(x)&=P(X\le x)=P(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\le x \}).
\end{align*}
Further, we can define an induced probability measure $\mu\colon \mathcal{B}\to[0,1]$ by
\begin{align*}
\mu(A) &= P(X\in A)=P(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in A \}).
\end{align*}

I read in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/976852/244596) that $\mu$ and $F$ uniquely determine eachother.

My question is: can we do this "in reverse", i.e. starting with a probability measure $\mu\colon \mathcal{B}\to[0,1]$, can we then get a unique random variable?

---

On $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B},P)$, I tried to do this starting with $\mu(A)=P(A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{B}$, where $P(A)=\mathrm{Leb}(A\cap[0,1])$. I believe this yields $X(x)=x$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, and $F(x)=\min(1,\max(0,x))$, so it works in this simple case.

Comment: $F_X(x)= P(X\leq x) = \mu((-\infty; x])$ for example

Comment: Yes, it works. You start with $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ where $\Omega=\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal F=\mathcal B$ (the Borelsets). Then function $X:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto x$ is a random variable. This with $P_X(A):=P(X\in A)=P(A)$ so $P_X=P$. The distribution of $X$ coincides with the probability measure that is part of the probability space.

Comment: @drhab Will the random variable always be the identity?

Comment: No. But if you want $P_X=P$ then you need $X=1_{\mathbb R}$ a.s. My former comment proves actually that for every distribution $P$ on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ a random variable $X$ can be found having $P$ as its distribution: $P_X=P$. Further it is not a very fruitful subject. If you take $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ as measurable space then you inherit quite some restrictions. Just keep it on the "mysterious" $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ willing to offer anything you want.